# MATLAB java heap space: GUI vs. java.opts

Tags: java, matlab

Can anyone explain the difference between using the preferences GUI inside matlab to set heap space and using a "java.opts" file to set it at startup?  I have the GUI maxed out, but it really doesn't seem to do anything (I get out of memory errors).  If I make a java.opts file with "-Xmx6000m" in it, then it works, but only if I start matlab from my home directory.

I'm running in Linux, matlab 2012b.

Comment: This may be sort of a tangent from your original question, but does the Out of Memory error that you are getting specifically indicate that it is java related?  If not, then increasing the java heap space might not help. In fact, in some circumstances it might make the problem worse, as you are allotting more memory for the java heap and now have less memory available for, say, creating large arrays, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it should do the same thing. Remember that if you change the setting via the MATLAB Preferences dialog, you will need to restart MATLAB for the setting to take effect.

I believe that the only difference is that the dialog gives you some (fairly sensible) limits, whereas you can enter anything you like via a `java.opts` file.

You can place the `java.opts` file either in your startup directory, or in `$MATLABROOT/bin/$ARCH`, where  `$MATLABROOT` is the MATLAB installation directory and `$ARCH` is your machine architecture. If you put it there you can start MATLAB in any directory and it will still take effect.

Comment: Yeah, it's a java error.  I think I just spaced out on the limit in the GUI.  It only goes to 35 megs or so, and I'm dealing with a few huge objects of several gigs.  java.opts is allowing me to go bigger than the GUI.

Comment: Also be aware that setting this (or the PATH) in the GUI will probably edit the config files in the main Matlab installation, like putting the file under $MATLABROOT, affecting all users and invocations, which may not be what you want. (Uh, especially with a 6 gig Java heap.) Doing `java.opts` in the startup dir will let you isolate the changes to just the programs that need it, and you can distribute it to other deployment locations along with the rest of your code so other users don't have to tweak their system.